# Running PowerShell code inside VBS with many nested quotes, in one line

Tags: powershell, vbscript, escaping, environment-variables, quotes

I'm starting to see double here from staring at this so long. I am trying to use an environment variable inside a script path that I'm going to launch from PowerShell, all initiated from a single line inside an mshta command run from a scheduled task on logon.

In case you were wondering, MSHTA can execute HTML/VBS/JS as if a local GUI app.

```
mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -NoLogo -Command """"& '\\$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\FOLDER1\FOLDER with Spaces\Folder3\Script-To-Run.ps1'"""""", 0 : window.close")
```

Premise: I have to do it this way to prevent momentary popups that flash onscreen when running from a scheduled task in user context. I cannot run this script in the System context.

I know that putting anything inside two single quotes gives me a string literal but if I try double quotes it seems to then use the space in the path. I've tried separating the two and concatenating them in all sorts of ways to no avail.

VBS equivalent of $env:USERDNSDOMAIN is

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERDNSDOMAIN%" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal/purpose is to execute a PowerShell script without displaying the `powershell.exe` console window, you can do this by running it from a VBScript script executed by `wscript.exe` (not `cscript.exe`).

Example VBScript script:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """d:\path name\whatever.ps1"" [parameter [...]]", 0, False
```

The second parameter of the `WshShell` object's `Run` method is `0`, so `powershell.exe` executes from a hidden window.

(Hint: The `-File` parameter to `powershell.exe` is generally easier to use than `-Command`. It must be the last parameter on the `powershell.exe` command line.)

End result: VBScript script runs the PowerShell script from a hidden window. Also, the VBScript itself has no console window, because you executed it using `wscript.exe` (the GUI host).

Comment: Already tried that. It works, except when launching from a scheduled task which is what I'm trying to do. When running from a scheduled task, it launches a brief window, both from running as wscript and cscript.

Comment: Sorry; can't reproduce that. You must be doing something different, because `wscript.exe` has no console window.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your scheduled task? I promise it's happening for me.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask about specifics of how to use the task scheduler in Windows; this is a programming Q&A site.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to use the task scheduler. I'm asking how to form escape quotes in such a way that I can use a variable inside a line of code.

Comment: VBScript uses `""` inside a quoted string to represent a single `"` (see my example VBScript script).